# How to determine if a RoleDefinition grants read access or not?

Tags: csom, sharepoint-rest-api, odata, roles, role-assignment

I have the role definitions like this:

`https://YOUR_TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/YOUR_SITE/_api/web/roledefinitions`

So this will return something like:

```
{_ObjectType_=SP.RoleDefinition, _ObjectIdentity_=1b751fa0-9c2c-b07f-b69b-4e7ff78d07ee|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:21df50b1-5453-4462-ba8e-5d1927afe837:web:231cf856-f71b-42b8-ba92-a15a5385e02c:rd:1073741825, BasePermissions={_ObjectType_=SP.BasePermissions, High=48, Low=134287360}, Description=Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or documents when given permissions., Hidden=true, Id=1073741825, Name=Limited Access, Order=160, RoleTypeKind=1}
```

I only care about role definitions that provide read permissions to a role assignment.

How can I use the RoleDefinition payload to determine "this is a role definition that provides read access?"

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the "Read" Role Definition, you can make a call to below Rest API:

```
https://YOUR_TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/YOUR_SITE/_api/web/roledefinitions?$filter=Name eq 'Read'&$select=Id,Name
```

You will get the 'Read' Role Definition ID in the output of the API call.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding but this is not the question I was asking. I was asking for a way to determine if a role definition has provided read access.